# Aligning Menu Right in Twenty Eleven Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

I'm pretty new at this stuff.  I just want to align the menu for this site to the right. Or even centered would be fine.  It's currently kind of floating around the middle in an awkward place.  The site is: http://www.socialbboutique.com.  I'm not sure what I need to do to fix or what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! [It's not enough to just post links to your website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/126000#126000). You should post relevant code and you do all of us a favor if you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify CSS file that is located at http://socialbboutique.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css and add the following code at the end of file.

Align to right:

```
#branding .only-search + #access div { padding-right: 0; }
#access div { margin: 0; }
```

Align to center:

```
#access ul { text-align: center; }
#access li { float: none; display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced those with :                                      #access ul {
 text-align: center;
}
#access li {
 float: none;
 display: inline-block;
 *display: inline; 
 *zoom:1;
}   but it didn't seem to move it...?